# Google App Engine .yaml file working locally but not when deployed

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

My `GAE` `PHP` `.yaml` file works locally but not when deployed. Everything worked fine up until I reorganized the folders my `.php` scripts were contained in. There is a `php` folder in the root of the app and the `.php` further organized into folders.

Current `YAML` file:

```
application: raven3mil
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /images
  static_dir: /static/images


# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: /login.php

error_handlers:
- file: /errors/404.html
```

File structure example:

```
+root
  +php
    +admin
      manageUsers.php
    +teacher
      lessons.php
    +student
      schedule.php
    dashboard.php
  +css
    index.css
    main.css
  +js
    +jquery
    +bootstrap
  login.php
```

I'm not sure why my `YAML` file works locally but not deployed. Can anyone give any insight?

Comment: What errors/warnings do you see in the log?

Answer (score 0):

If your scripts are using content from `static_dir`'s you need to make sure they are available to the application.

You can achieve that by adding `application_readable: true` to your `js`, `css` and `images` handlers.

You can read more about it here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig